# Changing directories with Bash

Tags: bash, autocomplete, cd-command

I was wondering if there was an easier way to pick directories to `cd` to within one's current directory.

For example, is there a way to just get a numbered list of the current directory and be able to do `cd 1`, `cd 2`, `cd 3`, etc.
Is there some other way to easily `cd` between sub directories in one's current directory?

Comment: You might want to look at Midnight Commander, which is a console-based "GUI" that displays directory listings and lets you change among them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you set the `autocd` option in your `~/.bashrc` you can change directories just by typing the name. Combined with Tab completion, you have only to type the first, unique characters and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move to your desired directory.

From the manual:

> If set, a command name that is the name of a directory is executed as
>   if it were the argument to the cd command. This option is only used by
>   interactive shells.

Add the option to your `~/.bashrc` with:

```
shopt -s autocd
```

If you use Zsh, set the option with:

```
setopt autocd
```

Comment: I was still using `$CDPATH` of old ...

Answer (score 3):

Add a function to your ~/.bashrc

```
mycd() { local x; shopt -s {null,dot}glob; select x in ../ */; do cd "$x"; break; done; }
```

usage: mycd

Comment: You might also want to use the `dotglob` option to allow hidden names.

Comment: @chepner: Good idea and thank you for quoting. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use completion! By default, this requires you to type a unique prefix of the directory you want to switch to, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. More precisely, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> completes the first unique prefix.

You can tweak completion through some [readline options](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Readline-Init-File-Syntax-1). In particular, set [`show-all-if-ambiguous`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-show_002dall_002dif_002dambiguous) to immediately display a list if there are multiple possible completions, or [`show-all-if-unmodified`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-show_002dall_002dif_002unmodified) to display a list only if the current prefix cannot be completed further due to ambiguity. These options go into the file `~/.inputrc`, for example:

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

You can configure bash to make repeated presses of <kbd>Tab</kbd> rotate through the possible completions. To do that, bind the key to [`menu-complete`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-menu_002dcomplete-_0028_0029) instead of the default [`complete`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-complete-_0028TAB_0029). In your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\t": menu-complete
```

Depending on your installation, completion after `cd` may either offer only directories, or all files. If it offers all files, you need to enable context-sensitive completion. Make sure that the [bash-completion](http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/) package is installed (it's available in most distributions) and that you have the line

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```

in your `~/.bashrc` (or in `/etc/bash.bashrc` if your distribution has that).

[Zsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) is an alternative shell that has many nice features for interactive use that bash lacks, including the possibility to choose completions in a menu. You may want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a single-character placeholder for each directory that you migrate to by assigning the current directory file path to an environment variable such as ...

```
    a=`pwd`
    b=`pwd`
```

etc..  Then you can jump to each directory with:

```
    cd $a
    cd $b
```

Be sure to use 'back-ticks' which mean to execute the command between the ticks and the equal sign assigns the output to the variable.

You can also assign the paths to single-character variables by writing them out also, such as:

```
    c="/home/user/projects/c++/headers/docs"
```

then you can change to that directory using...

```
    cd $c
```